# how to download a 100Gb file from Azure VM?

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup

I have a SQL Server running inside an Azure VM and need to bring a compressed backup to the local data center.

At the moment I'm using point-to-site vpn and this gives me just 4Mb/s.

What is a fast, reliable, and cost effective way to copy files from Azure?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a one-off activity or will it be part of e.g. a regular backup strategy?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2012 and 2014 support the ability to [back up directly to azure blob storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919148(v=sql.110).aspx). You can then simply download the file ([azcopy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx)?) to your onpremises data and restore it there or alternatively do the restore to the on-premises SQL Server directly from the blob storage backup.

Now if you already  have the file on the VM's disks, I would recommend you either use a tool like AZCopy to move it to blob storage so you can then download it, or perhaps ftp from the cloud VM directly to an on-premises FTP server.

Comment: That's definitely an option. I'll try ftp and blog storage options. Thanks.

Comment: azcopy is great - just make sure you use the restartable option (/Z)

Answer (score 0):

Put the compressed backup onto Azure Blob storage and download via [azcopy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/azcopy-transfer-data-with-re-startable-mode-and-sas-token.aspx).

Blob storage sits outside of the protection offered by the point-to-site vpn, so if thats a deal-breaker then all you can do is use standard file copy tools over the vpn.

However, if you can settle for the protection offered by SSL and further restrictions via SAS token, you'll be able to download pretty much as fast as your local datacenter can pull it down.